# Cointegration where first differences are not jointly stationary

Tags: time-series, cointegration, stationarity

Note: This is a crosspost from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493070/most-general-definition-of-cointegration) on cross-validated, where it did not receive an answer. I thought I might have better luck here.

I am looking for a rigorous and general treatment of cointegration. Unfortunately, many of the econometrics textbooks and papers I have found in this area either place a lot of restrictions on the timeseries involved or tend to be sloppy (assuming the sum of stationary timeseries is stationary, for example).

Here is one question I am interested in, for example. Consider a set of timeseries $x^i_t$ such that, for each $i$, $\Delta x^i_t$ is strictly stationary. I do not assume, however, that the differenced timeseries are jointly stationary. Assemble these timeseries into a vector $\mathbf{x}_t$ and define a cointegration vector to be any vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that
$$
\mathbf{v}^{\top} \mathbf{x}_t
$$
is strictly stationary.

The main question is, is the set of cointegration vectors closed under addition? If not, what is the minimal set of conditions one needs to ensure that this is true? Also, what is the situation when one considers weakly stationary timeseries rather than strictly stationary ones?

N.B. This question is based on the following [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374339/cointegration-of-multiple-time-series) at mathoverflow, which has, as yet, only received my very non-expert interest.

Comment: It seems $v_1^Tx_t$ and $v_2^Tx_t$ are jointly stationary, so their sum is also stationary. Hence it is closed under addition.

Comment: Why are those quantities jointly stationary?

Comment: Hi Aaron: strict ( same as strong ) stationarity implies that the joint distribution of the series is time invariant. This is stronger than the notion of weak stationarity.  As far as I know, cointegration assumes weak stationarity ( constant variance and constant mean )  because, in the gaussian case ( which is usually assumed ), weak implies strong. So, what is assumed is mean and variance constant over time. Then, this + gaussian assumption on noise implies strong. So,it's important to first define the type of stationarity one is referrring to and then more can be investigated after that.

Comment: I am interested in the answer for either definition of stationarity. I believe you can have strongly stationary timeseries that are not weakly stationary, fwiw. Regardless, I think it is reasonable to consider the first differenced time series being separately stationary without being jointly stationary, and that is the basis of the question.

Comment: Hi Aaron: The term "joint stationarity" refers to one series, not multiple. Also, AFAIK, strong implies weak.  Assuming, you are referring to weak stationarity in your question, I'll go back to your original question ( when I have more time )  and see if I can say something useful.

Comment: Aaron: In your original question, I think you mean to say "However, I do not assume that the differenced series are cointegrated".

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. That is not what I meant to say, however. In the usual situation for cointegration, the original time series are $I(1)$ which seems to have a bit of a slippery definition, but at a minimum means that the first differenced time series are stationary. Things are usually stated for a vector valued time series where stationarity means that the individual components are jointly stationary, but I am interested in relaxing that. See here for joint stationarity and multiple series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Joint_stationarity

Comment: Also, strong can not imply weak when the first and/or second moments don't exist.

Comment: Hi Aaron: if the first or second moments don't exist, then it can't be strong either. I don't understand your statement "things are usually stated for a vector valued time series where stationarity mean that the individual components are stationary.".  If each of the time series were stationary, then there's no need to consider a cointegrating vector because they are already stationary. My suggestion is to read anything by Johansen. He's not sloppy and he considers the case where there are more than 2 cointegrating vectors. Also, Katrina Juselius is another great writer on cointegration.

Comment: Hi Aaron: I'm sorry that I can't be much help but our terminology is so different. Maybe get Johansen's book on cointegration. He's very thorough and if you're good at math and linear algebra, you'll love it.

Comment: Thank you again. I haven't been able to get my hands on Johansen's book, but I'll keep looking. For what it's worth, it's the first differenced time series that are stationary, not the original time series.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116927/discussion-between-mark-leeds-and-aaron-bergman).